# IMU sensor coordinates for EKF

Tags: navigation, ros2, ekf, pose, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am using ekf to fuse multiple IMU. I was reading this portion

```
Measure +9.81 meters per second squared for the Z axis.
If the sensor is rolled +90 degrees (left side up), the acceleration should be +9.81 meters per second squared for the Y axis.
If the sensor is pitched +90 degrees (front side down), it should read -9.81 meters per second squared for the X axis.
```

1.Assume my robot is going 90 degrees vertically UPslope at 9.81m/s^2, my linear_accel.x will be 9.81x2? (gravity (+9.81) + forward acceleration (+9.81))?

2.Assume my robot is going 90 degrees vertically DOWNslope at 9.81m/s^2, my linear_accel.x will be 0? (gravity (-9.81) + forward acceleration (+9.81))?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403137/imu-sensor-coordinates-for-ekf/) by [MrOCW](https://answers.ros.org/users/95995/mrocw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2022-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe the answer to (1) is yes. Some flight simulators tilt the users backward (so +X is facing up) to simulate forward acceleration.

(2) is trickier intuitively (at least for me), but that must still be correct.

But to test this, I have an IMU whose spec sheet shows its coordinate frames as such. It's right-handed with +Z facing up.

[image: image description]

If I point the IMU such that +X is facing down into the ground, I get this:

```
linear_acceleration: 
  x: -10.0343017578125
  y: -0.4091726839542389
  z: -0.002991028130054474
```

Note that `x` is negative.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2022-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0